# Error while Processing a Basic Form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

The problem goes as follows:

File 1 which has the name of: **Lesson 17_Forms - Simple Form.php**
and
File 2 which has the name of: **Lesson 17_Forms - Process.php**

The contents of file 1 are as follows:

```
<html>
    <title>Lesson 17_Forms - Simple Form</title>
    <head>
        <center><h1>Lesson 17_Forms - Simple Form</h1></center>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action= "Lesson 17_Forms - Process.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
        <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The contents of file 2:

```
<html>
    <title>Lesson 17_Forms - Process</title>
    <head>
        <center><h1>Lesson 17_Forms - Process</h1></center>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            // Ultra-simple form processing
            // Just retrieve the value and return it to the browser

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            echo "{$username}: {$password}";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both files are in the same directory, when i am trying to process the form by clicking the submit button, i am receiving the following error:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Sat 12 May 2012 02:40:39 PM EEST Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1
>   mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are both files in the same directory?

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be any "visible" elements on the `head` tag. Your headers (`<h1>`) should be going to the body. Also, `<center>` is reluctant. Use CSS.

Comment: What if you don't use spaces in a filename?

Comment: @Truth: he can literally nothing, and you're overloading him now with the things he wouldn't understand in near future

Comment: Use `\ ` or `%20` instead of ` `(space) character in filename.

Comment: @Truth: in filenames - yes, but not in urls. To use spaces in urls you need to encode them, so this could be an issue

Comment: @Truth yes, they are, but I have doubt that browser might be looking for just `process.php`

Comment: @PLB: Not if he used quotes. I'm not saying it's alright to use spaces in file names, I just doubt the problem is there/.

Comment: I tried to add %20 instead of spaces but the error still there.

Comment: @CompilingCyborg: what url do you see after you submitted the form?

Comment: I missed one %20 while typing them that's why it didn't work. I highly appreciate your comments (zerkms). Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No spaces are allowed in url -> change the names to simple_form.php and process.php.

or if you want to keep spaces in name then replace all spaces by '%20' whenever you use it as a url.

Or the best option is to use urlencode -> it automatically replaces all non-allowed characters by their web acceptable placeholders.

```
<form action=<?php echo '"'.urlencode("Lesson 17_Forms - Process.php").'"'; ?> method="post">
```

Comment: While taking care of the symptoms. The base problem remains. You shouldn't need to hack your way through bad code, you need to fix it..

Comment: Yes, keeping spaces in url names is a bad practice. But the use of urlencode is unavoidable and must if he had to use to some external url with some data (which may contain some spaces etc). for example-> www.externalurl.com?data=abc%20bac%mma -> thats why I also provided him with a urlencode to solve un-allowed characters problem.

Comment: Forms actions rarely (and shouldn't really) contain get variables. There's generally no reason to use spaces in form actions. Since you've mentioned that, it's cool. you get my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have both files on the same directory. Also, eliminate any spaces in file names, while valid, they will cause massive headaches. So name your files something more like: `lesson17_forms_process.php`.

Also, after some modifications, this is the code I get:

```
<?php

//Initialize variables
$fields_set = false;
$username = "";
$password = "";

//Validity check
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $fields_set = true;
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lesson 17_Forms - Process</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Lesson 17_Forms - Process</h1>

<?php

//Display results if validity passed, or error in case it didn't.
if ($fields_set) {
    echo "{$username}: {$password}";
}
else {
    echo "Error! username or password not set!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

### Some Points

- I process all form data before I start sending HTML. Separate logic and display as much as possible.
- I removed the `h1` element from the `head` and placed it in the `body` (where it belongs). All page content must go in `body`.
- I removed the presentational element `<center>` and replaced it with CSS.
- I validate the input prior to processing.
- I display an error in case the form is not valid.

Comment: I would suggest you to rewrite your example to the more robust: "first retrieve and process the data - after make all the output"

Comment: @zerkms: I am well aware of that, if it were up to me, this example would be in perfect MVC pattern, but I don't want to confuse the OP with extra details. One obstacle at a time.

Comment: "but I don't want to confuse the OP with extra details" --- "Also, there shouldn't be any "visible" elements on the head tag. Your headers (<h1>) should be going to the body. Also, <center> is reluctant. Use CSS." --- you're so consistent today ;-)

Comment: I highly appreciate your comments. Thanks

Comment: @Truth: btw, sorry for that, didn't want to be that a$$, +1

Comment: @zerkms: I take all comments, good or bad, as constructive criticism. You don't need to be sorry, you made a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use your existing code, and modify it. With new file names.
I did also correct your HTML.

Create a file named: **form.php**, insert the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><h1>Submit form</h1></center>

        <form action="process.php" method="post">
            Username:<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
            <br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Create a file named: **process.php**, insert the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><h1>Lesson 17_Forms - Process</h1></center>
        <?php
            // Ultra-simple form processing
            // Just retrieve the value and return it to the browser

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            echo "{$username}: {$password}";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

That should work perfectly, remember to have both files in the same folder.

Comment: I have no idea why </html> doesn't work. But don't forget to place it in the end of both files. Stackoverflow seems to hide it, it's visible when I edit my post.

Comment: @Robinjoeh: All lines of your code must be indented 4 spaced in order to be included in the code block. I have edited for you, see now :)